# How to handle multiple space separator in Grass?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, lidar

I try to load a Lidar point cloud in .xyz format to Grass (in QGIS 2.0.1).

I tried to input the following options to the 'separator' field: `tab`, `'tab'`, `'\t'`. Just for the unlikely case that it worked I tried alse `' '`, `'space'`, `'newline'`, `'comma'` and `';'`.

Two things have changed. First: empty space between two apostrophes didn't work yesterday, but it works now (I don't know why). Phrasing it as `'space'` still doesn't work.

Second:  I found the data are actually separated by two or three spaces, not by a tab. When I set space as the separator, there is not the old wrong separator error, but Y coordinate seems wrong: it looks for it between the two spaces separating the fields. Writing `'  '` (double space) to the separator field doesn't help. So I rephrased this question to fit my problem better: **how to handle multiple space separator in Grass?**

First few lines of the .xyz file look like this:

```
  3453939.450  5633900.030   361.670
  3453941.750  5633900.020   361.720
```

Other options are the default ones, just the "statistic" is "median" instead of "n".

Comment: Do you have the option to use a text editor and replace all double spaces with a single space? That would probably be the easiest. BTW, if you want to use the words for the separator paramter, then it's without quotes. as separator=space or sparator=comma. The equivalent is separator=' ' or separtor=','.

Comment: Yes and no - the data I have are too big for ordinary editor (hundreds mega), but Vim can handle them. Well, can handle - it took half an hour to replace first two (double space) columns, and then I left for more than two hours and found Vim still working on the third column of the half-giga file. I must have done something wrong (running too much work at once, causing frequent read from/write to disc), but prospects of preprocessing much longer than running the Grass tool make me try to find some faster workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, [Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php) seems to be a wonderful text editor to handle large text files.

Here is what I did, after reading this [tutorial](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/228600-vim-101-a-beginners-guide-to-vim) for beginners and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860532/vim-regex-replace-multiple-consecutive-spaces-with-only-one-space) on StackOverflow.

```
:%s/ \+/ /g
```

The above command replaces multiple white spaces for a single whitespace (one can choose a different delimiter, though). It uses the following syntax:

> :%s/text/replacement text/g search through the entire document for text and replace it with replacement text.

the `\+` part addresses multiple whitespaces in the `text` argument.

I am not sure how long it takes to replace all the multiple spaces into your .xyz lidar files, but with the sample you provided the code worked. See below:

[image]

The result:

[image]

---

If the lidar text files are not that big, a simpler option could be a common text editor like NotePad++. According to [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Large_Text_Files) reference, it can handle files with 200Mb.

Use the regular expression `[\h]+` to find for multiple spaces and then, replace with a delimiter (for example, "comma").

Just as an explanation:

- "\h" will look for horizontal spaces without considering EOL (end of line),
- "+" recognizes more than one whitespace in a sequence.

For more information see the tutorial: [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions)

I added a screenshot as a mini tutorial about how to proceed with this advice. Sorry for not being in English.

1. Click the replace button
2. Select option "Regular expression"
3. Fill in Find = `[\h]+` and Replace = `,` (comma)
4. Click on "Replace all"

[image]

Save the new file an try to open it in Grass.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "tr" as well:

```
cat yourfile | tr -s ' ' ' ' > newfile.csv
```